# How to deal with too many irrelevant results for a elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I'm trying to implement a product search for a German e-commerce site and have great trouble to find the right resources about specific problems.

I had the problem that searches for a partial word wouldn't return viable results, e.g. match for `etikett` wouldn't result in documents containing `Rolletiketten`. 
Ngrams introduced too many problems, so I got rid of them again after some tests. I found out about word decomposition for the German language and tried some plugins. Now I'm getting far too many completely irrelevant results, e.g. searching for `rolletikett` returns documents containing `möbelrollen`, which is something completely different.

While I understand most of the mechanics and why I get those results, I have no clue how to fix my problems and as it seems I'm unable to find the right resources online to clear up some clouds.

A few hints would be awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With elasticsearch you should get the things you write out of the box (e.g. with a wildcard-search).
Maybe you are doing a boolean query that searches for whole words only.

I suggest the following links that go through the Query Language:

- Introductional: http://logz.io/blog/elasticsearch-queries/
- In detail: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Hope that helps, Christian

Tip: The document-mapping and exact query you are submitting will be helpful for others to assist in solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you said that introducing ngrams is causing issues, I think you may have ended up placing too much pressure on indexing. Changing the min and max grams value can help in that.
For example, below is an analysis filter that I am using and performs well:

```
"autocomplete": {
    "type": "edgeNGram",
    "min_gram": "1",
    "max_gram": "10"
}
```

Here is a another problem on stack overflow, the problem statement is different but the solution is relevant for this problem too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42592722/3133937

Answer (score 0):

"Now I'm getting far too many completely irrelevant results"

Try using `min_score`: [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-min-score.html)

Some of your ES queries may be broad enough that poor quality hits make it into your results. Just setting a threshold for score helps keep them at bay. For me, I had strong score 10 hits, then along with them were a ton of score 0 hits; unwanted. If you see this, I'd guess that your query could be more efficient, but at least `min_score` keeps the fluff down.

```
GET /myIndex/_search
{
    "from" : 0,
    "size" : 10,
    "min_score": 1,
    "query" : {
      "match": {
        "Title": {
            "query": "Bake a Cake",
            "fuzziness": 2
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```